# FieldInternalName instead of column name? Sharepoint Online Lists

Tags: list, sharepoint-online

As the title says, why do I need to use the `FieldInternalName` when working with Lists in SharePoint Online?

Is there any way of getting around this?

It's exhausting working with `FieldInternalNames` that look like: `_x0006wyz_3`

Of course you can just declare a variable to whatever `FieldInternalName` your working with, but you know what I mean.

Comment: I usually do a trick to avoid _xxxxx_ in the Internal names, create the field with the Internal name you want like 'BoolDisplayHidden' and than navigate to the field and change Title.. Doing this will not change the Internal name of the field..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's to ensure you get a column as uniquely as possible. The only thing better than the `FieldInternalName` is the `Guid` of the field.

You don't *have* to if you know the list only has 1 column with that name. But if you know the list contains multiple columns with the same display name, then you need to use the `FieldInternalName` to be sure you get the correct column.

E.g. if you have 2 columns with the display name "Body Display" (internal names could be `BodyDisplayOriginal` & `BodyDisplayHiddenCopy`) and you don't use their internal name to get the field, then you end up in a situation where you might get the wrong column - because you will just get whichever column SharePoint finds first.